# Need to Add An "Embed Watch Content" Build Phase to My iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

Oops.

I have an app that I've been rewriting from the ground up. The first version had a Watch App, and I wanted to get the Watch app stuff out of the calculation, so I removed the project dependency and the "Embed Watch Content" build phase.

No problem...except that now it's time to start working on the Watch app again.

I can add the dependency, no problem, but the "Embed Watch Content" phase doesn't seem to be working out for me.

I suspect that it's just a "Copy Files" phase, renamed, but I must not be implementing it correctly.

What is the proper way to establish a new "Embed Watch Content" phase in an existing target?

Comment: Hmm...Kinda looks like I need to completely delete the old target, and create a new one.

Comment: Um...why the downvote? This is a totally legit question. If you have an answer, then please provide the answer. As you can see, it appears as if there really is no answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

It looks like the `Embed Watch Content` build phase is just a renamed version of a `Copy Files` build phase. If you need to reattach a watch app we were able to create the `Embed Watch Content` build phase by creating a new `Copy Files` build phase and simply changing the title to `Embed Watch Content`. Then set the subpath to `$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/Watch` And add your watch app to the files to copy.

Comment: Thanks. I think that it did more "behind the scenes" stuff. I suspect that some build parameters were also changed. It's probably something that I could do by hand, if I figured out all the knobs it twiddled. However, that was all some time ago, and I haven't tried since. I'll bet that it's a simpler thing now.

Comment: I switched to this being the accepted answer, because it is now the way it works (it wasn't, back when the question was asked).

Answer (score 1):

OK. It looks like you definitely need to delete all Watch targets, and create a new one. There was no way that I could link an existing detached target with an existing detached phone app.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy. Just create a new dummy watch target. Then replace the `.app` entry in "Embed Watch Content" with the original `.app`. Now you can delete the dummy targets and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the latest version of Xcode fixes the issues I originally encountered. I did just that, recently, and it worked.